# ThingsBoard default acces port

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip, port, thingsboard

At this moment I have a community version of Thingsboard installed, in an EC2 instance with an OS Ubuntu 18.04.  I access the thingsboard application through the ip of my server and a port in this case 8080 (`http://my_ip:8080/`)

In the thingsboard documentation, the general configuration of the system variables can be found in the `thingsboard.yml` file located in `/usr/share/thingsboard/conf`.

That said, it is possible to access the ThingsBoard application through port `80`, that is, it is possible to access the ThingsBoard application with an address similar to `http://my_ip/`?

I tried changing the port `8080` to `80` in the section:

```
server:
# Server bind address
address: "$ {HTTP_BIND_ADDRESS: 0.0.0.0}"
# Server bind port
port: "$ {HTTP_BIND_PORT: 8080}"
```

This did not work, however I tried another port (for example `2020`) and if you can enter using `http://my_ip:2020/`

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to follow this official guide, detailing the steps needed to install an HAProxy server sitting in front of your ThingsBoard service on your VM.

This way, HAProxy is the one listening on port `80` and doing the balancing to the internal port `8080` used by TB.

This tutorial goes the extra-mile by also detailing how to setup certbot to handle TLS certificates.

https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/pe/add-haproxy-ubuntu/